# Mis-click during a review. No way to correct my review?

Tags: support, review-queues

I was doing a review (from triage), and I clicked on the wrong button (<kbd>Needs community edit</kbd> instead of "Needs details and clarity").

Is there a way to correct my review ?

Comment: Related: [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360198/visual-design-changes-to-the-review-queues) | Design changes to review queues are coming, and they include a move away from the one-click-and-done style of the current system. The single ribbon of action buttons are being replaced with [a set of radios and a "submit" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yzo3n.png). Ideally, this should help reduce the amount of accidental reviews.